# How to make the bot charge coins regardless the state of the user in the voice channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I’m making a bot with a coin system, one man has already helped me (thx very much, @Federico Grandi
) so that the bot check user in the voice channel and how much he is there. Now I do not know how to make the bot list the coins immediately after a minute has passed, not when the user has logged out.

```
let coins = require("./coins.json");

let voiceStates = {}

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

  let { id } = oldState

  if (!oldState.channel) {

    console.log('user joined voice channel');

    voiceStates[id] = new Date()

  } else if (!newState.channel) {
    console.log('user left voice channel')

    let now = new Date()

    let joined = voiceStates[id] || new Date()

    let dateDiff = now.getTime() - joined.getTime();

    if (oldState.selfMute === true && newState.selfMute === true){
        console.log('2');
    }

    if (dateDiff > 60 * 1000) {
      console.log('user earned 200 coins');

      coins[message.author.id] = {
        coins: coins[message.author.id].coins + 200

       };
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: So do you want the bot to send a message with the amount of coins a user has one minute after they have joined the voice channel?

Comment: @cherryblossom No, I wrote it to myself in the console to check, in the future I will clean it... I want the bot simply charge coins to the user every minute if he spent that minute in the voice channel with the microphone turned on. Coins are stored in <coins.json>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let coins = require("./coins.json");

let voiceStates = {};

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  let { id } = oldState;

  if (!oldState.channel) {
    console.log('user joined voice channel');

    voiceStates[id] = { joined: new Date() };
    // If the user is not muted...
    if (!newState.selfMute) {
      // ...execute a callback a minute later (this may be cancelled: see below)
      voiceStates[id].timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // charge the coins
        // do whatever after the user has been on the channel unmuted for a minute
      }, 60000);
    }
  } else if (!newState.channel || newState.selfMute) {
    // If the user left the channel or muted themselves and there is a timeout...
    if (voiceStates[id].timeout) {
      // ...cancel the timeout
      clearTimeout(voiceStates[id].timeout);
      voiceStates[id].timeout = undefined;
    }

    if (!newState.channel) {
      // rest of your code for if the user left the channel...
      console.log('user left voice channel');

      let now = new Date();

      // Only difference from your code is here
      let joined = voiceStates[id] && voiceStates[id].joined || new Date();

      let dateDiff = now.getTime() - joined.getTime();

      if (oldState.selfMute === true && newState.selfMute === true) {
        console.log('2');
      }

      if (dateDiff > 60 * 1000) {
        console.log('user earned 200 coins');

        coins[message.author.id] = {
          coins: coins[message.author.id].coins + 200
        };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This uses [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) to charge the coins after a minute. If the user leaves the channel or mutes themselves, this timer will be cancelled/cleared.